# Compare dataframe to list of dictionary values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe:

```
d = {'col1':['2q','48', '48-49']}
test = pd.DataFrame(d)


col1

0 2q
1 48 
2 48-49
```

And a dictionary for mapping:

```
mupcs_to_pc_mapping = {'24': ['48-49', '48', '49'], #M2
                   '23': ['50-51', '50', '51'], #M3
                   '22': ['52-53', '52', '53'], #M4
                   '21': ['54-55', '54', '55'], #M5
                  }
```

I would like to test each value of the test dataframe to see if it exists in the mupcs_to_pc_mapping dict values.

So the final result is something like:

```
0 False
1 True
2 True
```

I tried a variation of:

```
test['col1'].isin(mupcs_to_pc_mapping.values())
```

and

```
test['col1'].any(value for value in mupcs_to_pc_mapping.values())
```

but both of them result in an error.

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need

```
test.col1.isin(sum(mupcs_to_pc_mapping.values(),[]))
Out[477]: 
0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

Mentioned by cold in the comment `itertools.chain`

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(mupcs_to_pc_mapping.values()))
```

Comment: You should consider the use of `itertools.chain` instead of `sum`, which is much slower

Comment: My tests indicate that isin + itertools is the fastest here... cool!

Answer (score 5):

You can also do :

```
test.isin(pd.DataFrame(mupcs_to_pc_mapping).stack().values)

   col1
0  False
1  True
2  True
```

Answer (score 3):

First, invert your mapping:

```
m = {v : k for k in mupcs_to_pc_mapping for v in  mupcs_to_pc_mapping[k]}
```

Now, use `map` and test for `NaN`s.

```
test.col1.map(m).notnull()

0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a set that is the union of all dictionary values

```
test.col1.isin(set.union(*map(set, mupcs_to_pc_mapping.values())))

0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```